# 404 issues trying to import js files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've tried answers from other posts, but they are not working for me.

Folders are: (py code is in 'art', flask is run from there)

```
art
  static
    css
    html
    img
    js
      lib
```

Import in html is:

```
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js')}}"> </script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/Main.js')}}"> </script>
```

Error from Flask run:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 10:46:17] "GET /art HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 10:46:17] "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('static',%20filename='/js/bin/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js')%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 10:46:17] "GET /%7B%7Burl_for('static',%20filename='/js/Main.js')%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

From the Safari Web Inspector:

[image: Web Inspector]

Thanks.

EDIT: .py code:

```
@app.route("/art")

def index():
  return """
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <title>CD Test</title>

        <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js')}}"> </script>
        <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/Main.js')}}"> </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h2>CD Test.</h2>
        <hr>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img id="Pic" src="url/xxx.jpg" onclick="openFullscreen()"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>

    </html>
  """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Judging by the web inspector error your template is served as is and is not rendered. Can you post the code of the function that handle the route "/art" ?

Comment: Code added to original post. The picture does render (I had to fudge the sample URL because you can't post http etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work. You can not return template tag (the pieces of code in `{{ }}`) directly. You have to render the template first. I suggest you go [there](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for a quick tutorial/example on how to render a templates.

Comment: Nice. If this answer helped you please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

adding to Niko B's good advice to render templates,
this simplified directory structure and code helped me run Flask with Javascript:

```
art/
- __init__.py  #if art directory needs to be a module
- main.py  #where Flask is run
- templates/
--- home.html
- static/
--- home.js
```

**main.py:**

- point `@app.route` to `('/')` instead of `('/art')`, as the index page of http://127.0.0.1:8080
- return `render_template` per Niko B

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**home.html:**

- better (best?) practice than putting it in `main.py`

```
<head>
    <script src="/static/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table id="art">
        <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Van Gogh</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onClick="addButtons()">Add Buttons</button>
</div>
</body>
```

**home.js:**

- referred to in `home.html` in `<script>`

```
function addButtons() {
    let table = document.getElementById('art');
    let rows = table.rows;

    // Loop through each row(except the header)
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

        let cols = rows[i].cells;
        let lastCol = rows[i]['cells'][cols.length - 1];

        // Create a new button element
        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'View';

        // Append the button to the last column
        lastCol.appendChild(button);

    }
    }
```

With terminal in `art` directory,
Run `python main.py`,
Open http://127.0.0.1:8080/

[image]

Click on "Add Buttons", and a "View" button appears in same row as "Van Gogh".

**Much thanks to these references!**

- Flask Project Layout https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/layout/
- "CSS and JS returning 404 when linking in HTML (Python Flask)" https://ask.replit.com/t/css-and-js-returning-404-when-linking-in-html-python-flask/23113/3
- How to add Javascript to HTML https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html
- How to add a button to a HTML table dynamically using JavaScript https://programmersportal.com/how-to-add-a-button-to-an-html-table-dynamically-using-javascript/